# Which services on AWS can be used to implement a realtime database similar to Firebase?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have used the amazing realtime database on Firebase for my project. But the service is unstable in my country recently. I want to implement a similar functionality on AWS. But I don't know which services can be used to create a realtime database. I've read the Amazon DynamoDB document and I think DynamoDB is static. How can multiple clients sync to data changes with DynamoDB? Or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the option you have in AWS is to use a combination of following services.

- AWS Dynamodb (For database & stream events to Lambda)
- AWS Lambda (Publish messages to AWS IOT)
- AWS IOT (Websockets pub-sub)

The combination is mainly around AWS IOT which provides the realtime messaging support to web browsers. Check [this article](https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357) for more information.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'll dive into the article to seek some inspiration^_^